# Cassandra and JSON

Tags: json, cassandra, bigdata, nosql

Alright so, I'm taking massive amounts in what is supposed to be JSON format and I'm trying to insert it into a Cassandra cluster. The problem is that the data doesn't have a standard key:value format so I believe its not actually JSON.

Here's an example of the data:

```
'{"15151162":"6f0aa7ebc60af9b6dd5992341e155138b3ea369a","15149182":"c141929a6ccc6157f4de7055ea565e7a83f59aea","15144225":"f70a2cdecee0e7e9fe85819e74d0e09d36060909"}'
```

So then keeping that in mind I'm wondering and I know this is somewhat opinion, but do I have to pull apart and then mass insert the data or is there a better way where I could just map them to columns using some feature of CQL/Cassandra.

Also as additional information we're talking around 28 million records so ideally I'd like to do it using the CQL/Cassandra instead of reorganizing the objects in a programming language.

I am familiar with Java, C++ and SQL, fairly new to nosql/Hybrid nosql.

Thanks

Comment: You example data is valid JSON. Recent C* versions have native [JSON support](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cassandra-2-2-json-support). You can insert JSON into a table and the keys will be mapped to columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have a key then create one as you ingest it by creating a guid and format the record like so.

```js
{
  "key": "3fa55ea6-de8b-4b6f-b11e-5a3701982c65",
  "type": "weird data",
  "data": {
    "15144225": "f70a2cdecee0e7e9fe85819e74d0e09d36060909",
    "15149182": "c141929a6ccc6157f4de7055ea565e7a83f59aea",
    "15151162": "6f0aa7ebc60af9b6dd5992341e155138b3ea369a"
  }
}
```

Adding a type field is very helpful for when the next programmer actually has to deserialize this data. A version field is probably a good idea too.